# I want to add a guard for my gnosis wallet in The Rinkeby Testnet, But it always failed

Tags: rinkeby, gnosis-safe, gnosis

I've seen this [add a transaction guard](https://help.gnosis-safe.io/en/articles/5496893-add-a-transaction-guard), but it does not work correctly. The guard is `DebugTransactionGuard` in [safe-contracts](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/examples/guards/DebugTransactionGuard.sol).

The tenderly debug session is here: [enter link description here](https://dashboard.tenderly.co/public/safe/safe-apps/simulator/2e1a5709-1301-423d-9da2-a972b4d73cb7?trace=0.0.5)

The `DebugTransactionGuard` contract is 0x95A2D7BE8bbA43fd58f07ee6fe76c73565D066B8 in the rinkeby testnet.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending `setGuard` transaction to the Safe Singleton contract (`0xd9db270c1b5e3bd161e8c8503c55ceabee709552`) instead of your Proxy contract (`0xb278a004bc0b41aaa92459767c1c957e19809f99`).